# In R package gt, can you merge columns and format results at same time?

Tags: r, gt

Suppose I have two columns representing upper and lower confidence bounds

```
df <- tibble(upper_bounds = c(0.00000123, 0.2323223),
             lower_bounds = c(0.12334455, 0.1234556))
```

Is there a way to both merge those columns and format them using the gt package?

As independent columns I can format them:

```
tab <- df %>%
 gt() %>%
 fmt_number( columns = c(upper_bounds, lower_bounds), decimals = 3)
```

and I can combine them

```
tab <- df %>%
 gt() %>%
  cols_merge(
    columns = c(lower_bounds, upper_bounds),
    pattern = "({1}, {2})"
  )
```

But I can't figure out how to both merge and format at the same time.  Is it possible? I could, alternatively, go back to my original dataset and format upper/lower bounds there, but I'm curious if I can do it within gt.

Comment: Just combine the two operations. (`fmt_number()` first, and then `cols_merge()`

Comment: For crying out loud.  I thought I tried that but clearly not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your request, but you can just feed the result of your `fmt_number()` call to the `cols_merge()` call:

```
tab <- df %>%
  gt() %>%
  fmt_number( columns = c(upper_bounds, lower_bounds), decimals = 3) %>% 
  cols_merge(
    columns = c(lower_bounds, upper_bounds),
    pattern = "({1}, {2})"
  )
```